# Why "\001" === "\u0001" is true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, escaping

the code is:

```
console.log("\1" === "\u0001");//true
console.log("\01" === "\x01");//true
console.log("\001" === "\u0001");//true
```

why  `"\001" === "\u0001"` is true,who can tell me why?

Comment: Because they're all the same character? If you were expecting the form seen in the literal syntax to be compared, you'd need to escape the `\ ` character. `console.log("\\1" === "\\u0001");// false`

Comment: They are all the [same character](http://codepoints.net/U+0001).  Those are different ways to [escape](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those strings are a single character; namely, [Unicode code point 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).

Those are different ways of escaping it in the [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals).